# Nothing renders onto the screen even though I call my render method

Tags: java, while-loop, render

Why my `tick();` method being called, but not my `render();` method is the question here.
So, I have a class that holds my updating and my rendering here:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MapI extends Map {

    int players = 8, islands = 8;

    private int dimAm, irAm, golAm, emAm;

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        while(irAm < 48) {
            tickIr();
        }
        while(dimAm < 4) {
            tickDim();
        }
    }

    public void tickDim() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dimAm += 1;
        System.out.println(dimAm + " diamonds");
    }

    public void tickIr() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        irAm += 1;
        System.out.println(irAm + " iron");
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(30, 10, 50, 50); // dim gen(s)
        g.drawString(dimAm + "", 41, 29);
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(40, 20, 30, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(30, 100, 50, 50); // yellow base
    }

}
```

Here's the Map class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class Map {

    protected int players, islands;

    public abstract void tick();

    public abstract void render(Graphics g);

}
```

What is happening is, when my `run()` method in my Game class is called, it has a `while(running)`, and inside that loop is where I specify to render and update:

```
public void run(){

    init();

    while(running){
        render();
        tick();
    }

    stop();

}

public synchronized void start(){
    if(running)
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    if(!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With this, I should both render and update, but, as of right now, all that goes on is updates. I think that my problem might come with

```
@Override
public void tick() {
    while(irAm < 48) {
        tickIr();
    }
    while(dimAm < 4) {
        tickDim();
    }
}
```

, which is inside of MapI. What I think is happening is nothing else will render until none of these loops are still running, but then again, I don't know how to bypass that.
My GameAspect class that houses the render method is here:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import blaze.game.gfx.Assets;
import blaze.game.maps.MapI;

public class GameAspect implements Runnable {

    private Display display;
    public int width, height;
    public String title;

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics g;

    private MapI map1;

    public GameAspect(String title, int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.title = title;

        map1 = new MapI();
    }

    private void init(){
        display = new Display(title, width, height);
        Assets.init();
    }

    private void tick(){
        map1.tick();
    }

    private void render(){
        bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        //Clear Screen
        g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        //Draw Here!

        map1.render(g);

        //End Drawing!
        bs.show();
        g.dispose();
    }

    public void run(){

        init();

        while(running){
            render();
            tick();
        }

        stop();

    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)
            return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        if(!running)
            return;
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Wheres the render method? only calling it with a argument will render into thegraphics, for paint in the screen you need to override paintComponent(Graphics) somewhere

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos it's in the class MapI.

Comment: Seeing as `render` expects an argument and you're not supplying it, how does this even compile?

Comment: Whre the render on the run() class

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos ??, what do you mean.

Comment: In your `run` method: `while(running){
        render();
        tick();
    }`

Comment: @luckydog32 yes, I still don't understand what you guys are asking me.

Comment: post full code then if you dont know

Comment: Your `render` method takes a `Graphics` object `public void render(Graphics g)`. But when you call it you pass no argument `render()`. So if it was trying to call your `run` method it wouldn't compile since it's missing an argument. Its possible that there's another render method it is calling that takes no arg.